# Relationships - can I get child channel_short_name?

Tags: relationships

I have a relationship field where the parent can select multiple children from multiple channels. When it comes time to display everything, I need to know what channel the child entry comes from so I can display the proper fields.

I tried:

```
{parent}
{parent:channel_short_name} - <b>{parent:title}</b><br />
{/parent}
```

but no go. It literally just displays "{parent:channel_short_name}".

Any ideas? Just go get Playa?
Thanks
Amanda

Edit: Haha, yea never mind. I must have had a typo. It works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This example in the docs](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/relationships.html#parent-entries-which-stores-have-which-pizza) suggests that your code should be:

```
{parents}
{parents:channel_short_name} - <b>{parents:title}</b><br />
{/parents}
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I must have had my head in the clouds.

Comment: Amanda, don't forget to mark Sean's answer as accepted if it worked for you.